# Android - How to read Accessibility for touch listener

Tags: android, accessibility

I am using a touch listener for Android. When I activate accessibility in Android it reads like "Dobule tap to Activate." But When I double tap action is not working. Insteed Action works when I touch with double finger in that view. How to change the accessibility message? I want to read like "Touch with double finger to activate". Please help me on this.

```
ed_text = findViewById(R.id.ed_text);
        ed_text.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"ACTION_DOWN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"ACTION_UP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"ACTION_CANCEL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Vijayadhas Chandrasekaran You should use OnClickListener instead or override performAccessibilityAction for your view in your custom view class,or via setAccessibilityDelegate.